# How to cleanup useRef in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have this component, so I want to clean up in useEffect.  I googled the issue and there is no helpful information.

```
const LoadableImg = ({src, alt}) => {
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

let imageRef = useRef(null);


useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) return;
    if (imageRef.current) {
        imageRef.current.onload = () => setIsLoaded(true);
    }
    return () => {
        imageRef.current = null;
    };
}, [isLoaded]);

return (
    <div className={isLoaded ? 'l_container_loaded' : 'l_container'}>
        <img ref={imageRef} className={isLoaded ? "l_image_loaded" : 'l_image'}
             src={src}
             alt={alt}/>
    </div>
) };
```

I can't figure out how to clean up in useEffect.

**UPDATE**
added another useEffect, according to  Arcanus answer.

```
const LoadableImg = ({src, alt}) => {
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

let imageRef = useRef(null);


useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) return;
    if (imageRef.current) {
        imageRef.current.onload = () => setIsLoaded(true);
    }

}, [isLoaded]);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        imageRef.current = null;
    };
},[])


return (
    <div className={isLoaded ? 'l_container_loaded' : 'l_container'}>
        <img ref={imageRef} className={isLoaded ? "l_image_loaded" : 'l_image'}
             src={src}
             alt={alt}/>
    </div>
)};
```

Comment: Did you get a warning to clean up? From what I've worked with so far, when you dismount, the ref is automatically destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, but the error appears sometimes. It seems cleanup is either done or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with a ref, then you will need to remove the onload function, but you do not need to null out `imageRef.current`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) return;
    const element = imageRef.current;
    if (element) {
        element.onload = () => setIsLoaded(true);
        return () => {
            element.onload = null;
        }
    }
}, [isLoaded]);
```

That said, i recommend you do **not** use a ref for this. A standard onLoad prop will work just as well, without the need for all the extra logic for adding and removing the event listener:

```
const LoadableImg = ({ src, alt }) => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={isLoaded ? "l_container_loaded" : "l_container"}>
      <img
        className={isLoaded ? "l_image_loaded" : "l_image"}
        src={src}
        alt={alt}
        onLoad={() => setIsLoaded(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your instance, the only time you want to use useEffect is when DOM is fully loaded, and your ref is ready. Hence you need a hook

E.g.

```
function useHasMounted() {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);
  return hasMounted;
}
```

Then your Component should be corrected to be as follows

```
const hasMounted = useHasMounted();

useEffect(() => {
        if (hasMounted) {
           imageRef.current.onload = () => setIsLoaded(true);
        }
}, [hasMounted]); //<-- call once when dom is loaded.
```

I understand you want to call onload whenever images is loaded, however, please do note this do not always work because images loaded from cache does not call `onload`.